# Need matching opening and closed brackets in regular expression with dynamic value in between

Tags: regex

We have a requirement to enter values like this in a textbox:

```
((1 OR 2) AND (3)) or (1 AND (2 or 3 AND 4))
```

The numbers `1`,`2` and `3 are dynamic in nature based on the number of rows in a grid.

There are three validations that we want to accomplish.

1. restrict the numbers entered which will be based on the number of rows in a grid;
2. should only allow `AND` and `OR` text;
3. parenthesis should be well formed;

Preferably we need the regular expression in JavaScript so that it can be changed during run time.

Comment: Please post your attempts at creating this regex.

Comment: I am new to regex.(\((?:(?>[^()]+)|(?[1-3]|OR|AND ))*\)) is what I was trying. Obviously [1-3] has to change.

Comment: Err, JS doesn't support atomic groups, and I don't think that `(? ... )` is a valid group. If you meant `(?| ... | ...)` then this is not supported either in JS.

Comment: Is there always exactly one set of outside parentheses that enclose exactly two sets of inner parentheses? If you want me to see your reply, write `@zx81` at the front.

Answer (score 0):

this pattern `(\((?:([1-4]|\s|and|or)|(?1))+\))|(?2)` when replaced with nothing should eat up every thing if your text box is valid and leave you with something if it is not.
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mS3sI0)

Desclaimer:
it will not validate something like `((1 OR 2) AND (3)) or (1 AND (2 or 3 AND ))` where the last `AND` is not followed by an argument, it only checks for balanced brackets.